# Matlab: How to delete all columns in a matrix if it contains more than some specific number of NaN values

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to delete all columns which have more than some specific number of NaN (Let's say 5 NaNs). Is there any way to do it without loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No loop needed:

```
matFixed = MAT( :, sum( isnan( MAT ) ) <= 5);
```

Step by step:

```
nanMat = isnan(MAT); % convert MAT to logical with 1 indicating value is a NAN
nNanInCol = sum(nanMat); %compute the number of NANs in each col
colIdx = nNanInCol <= 5; % determine which columns are "valid"
matFixed = MAT(:, colIdx); % create new matrix using only the good columns of MAT
```

Comment: You're welcome. Also, in step 3, the logical expression for `colIdx` is true for the columns that are "good" so your description may be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy:

```
%# define a matrix with NaNs
A = rand(10); %# 10x10 array
A(A<0.5) = NaN; %# each column contains on average 5 NaNs

%# count NaNs
nanCt = sum(isnan(A),1);

%# remove columns with too many NaNs
A(:,nanCt > 5) = [];
```